# Regex to match both PhD and ph.d

Tags: python, regex, string

I am trying to read a CSV file of faculty members. My aim is to count the frequency of each standardized degree (like PhD, Md, JD, etc.) in the file. The file contains different variations of the same degree (like PhD, Ph.D and Phd).

So far I have used `.lower.split()` to convert the text into a list with all lowercase characters, but the list contains different versions of the same degree like(phd vsph.d vs ph.d.).

Comment: What about "removing all punctuation [and possibly whitespace]  characters"?

Comment: Haven't tried removing whitespace. I guess removing both could work.I will try it

Answer (score 4):

You could try using `re.findall` with the following pattern, for Ph.D.

```
s = 'Richard Feynman had a Ph.D. and Albert Einstein also had a phd'
print(len(re.findall('\\b(?i)ph\.?d\.?\\b', s)))

2
```

### Demo

If you wanted to count all degree types together, then you could still use a single call to `re.findall` using a regex pattern with an alternation:

```
(?i)ph\.?d\.?|md|jd
```

If you needed separate counts, then you could make separate calls to `re.findall`.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the immediate problem, you could also remove punctuation.

```
.lower().replace('.', '')
```

Comment: @ThatBird Yes they will. They're both converted to 'phd'.

Comment: Removing all dots might fix the problem with `Ph.D.`, but it could lead to side effects.  E.g. a sentence ending/beginning `... he said to Joseph.Don't do that again`. Your logic might flag the text around the full stop as being a `phd` when it's really not.

Comment: This is better solved by a regex, and also, you're replacing period with a space

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sure, but language problems are inherently fuzzy. Your initial regex solution had the same bug, and if you remove that feature then you don't capture instances like `...he said toph.D J. Hoffmann...`. Correctness in the face of typos is not a solved problem.

Comment: @ThatBird Thank you regarding the space. I probably shouldn't be up this late. As far as the regex, I don't completely agree. While regex is probably a standard approach, if OP is new to python and/or programming (it's their first post), then python's regex quirks probably aren't a great place to start. Ignoring the problem at hand, in large-scale problems typically approaches with hash tables mapping common synonyms will scale better than regex solutions.

Comment: @HansMusgrave notice how OP has tagged the question under "regex" also !

Comment: @ThatBird Paolo edited the question to add the "regex" tag.

Comment: Oh, did not see that but well, it's always good to learn I believe

Answer (score 0):

```
re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]','', degree.lower())
```

Answer (score 0):

Phd is not the only degree in the world, here is the robust solution

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
message = "I am holding a B.tech, M.Tech and Ph.D in Computer Science"
degrees = ["btech", "bsc", "mtech", "phd"]
tokens = word_tokenize(message)
for token in tokens:
    for character in string.punctuation:
        token = token.replace(character, "")
    token = token.lower()
    if token in degrees:
        print(token)
```

The output will be like this,

```
btech
mtech
phd
```

**Explanation**

1. word_tokenize is from natural language toolkit which separates individual words from the sentence. We call the individual words as tokens generally.
2. We are iterating over tokens, removing their punctuation and converting them to lower case and comparing them to our degrees list to get the list of degrees.

You can also you a dict to get the fancy names out of the degree keyword like this,

```
degrees = {"btech" : "B.Tech", "mtech" : "M.Tech", "phd":"Ph.D"}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

text = "PhD Ph.D Phed phd vsph.d vs ph.d."
regex_pattern = r"[P|p]h\.?[D|d]"
matches = re.findall(regex_pattern, text)
for match in matches:
   print("Full match: %s" % (match))
```

regex_pattern = r"[P|p]h.?[D|d]"

**r""** - tells python its a Regular expression pattern, not just any string
**[P|p]** - match when a word starts with "P" or "p" followed by ..
**h** - "h" followed by ..
**\.** - "." (notice the escape here '.') followed by ..
**[D|d]** - "D" or "d"

Escape is needed for **.** because it has a meaning in Regular expression = (any character).

Comment: "tells python its a Regular expression pattern, not just any string" not really, it tells python not to escape characters, i.e. special characters have no special meaning "(\n) is not a newline, it's backslash n"